# API data not showing on the page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get data of currency prices using API, but somehow the data is not showing on the page. In the browser, console works everything fine.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Output:

> price: undefined

My code:

```
<script>

    $(function (){

        var $data = $('#data');

        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json',
            url: 'https://cors.io/?https://www.freeforexapi.com/api/live?pairs=EURUSD',
            success: function(data) {

                console.log(data);

                $.each(data, function([i, price) {
                    $data.append('<li>price:  '+ price.rate + '</li>');
                });

            }
        });
    });

</script>

<ul id="data"></ul>
```

Comment: Try `price.EURUSD.rate`. Or loop over `data.rates`. Check the returned JSON.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Made a working example for you, you have to loop the **rates** tag of the **JSON** you are getting, not the root one, like you was doing. Also, there was a lost **"["** inside your code.

```js
$(function()
{
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        url: 'https://cors.io/?https://www.freeforexapi.com/api/live?pairs=EURUSD',
        success: function(data)
        {
            console.log(data);
            
            $.each(data.rates, function(i, price)
            {
                $('#data').append('<li>price:  ' + price.rate + '</li>');

            });
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul id="data"></ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

The URL you're fetching doesn't return an array.  The response is an object with the rates nested at the second level.

```
{
  "rates": {
    "EURUSD": {
        "rate": 1.157282,
        "timestamp":1539727098144
    }
  },
  "code":200
}
```

In your example, you need to access the 'rates' property on the response, and iterate over that, then access the 'rate' sub property on each curreny pair.

```
$.each(data.rates, function([currencyPair, rateInfo) { 
    $data.append('<li>price:  '+ rateInfo.rate + '</li>');
});
```

Comment: Maybe he wants it to also work when "?pairs=EURUSD" is not passed as a param, in which case it probably returns several rates (one for each "pair", whatever that means).

Comment: @Jordan Burnett Thank you!

Comment: @Jeto - had the same thought and have updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

A few changes, you can remove the loop and access the data object directly within your success function. Furthermore, we can improve upon readability by using [Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

Here is the code:

```js
$(function() {

  var $data = $('#data');

  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    url: 'https://cors.io/?https://www.freeforexapi.com/api/live?pairs=EURUSD',
    success: function(data) {
      $data.append(`<li>price:  ${data.rates.EURUSD.rate}</li>`);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="data"></ul>
```